Return new task with return value, using the Task constructor with async action
Maybe someone can explain, why this is working:
var task = new Task(async () =>
{
    var noSolution = await AsyncMethodWithBoolReturnValue();

    if (noSolution)
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }
});

But using the generic to specify the return value is not possible?
var task = new Task<bool>(async () =>
{
    var noSolution = await AsyncMethodWithBoolReturnValue();

    if (noSolution)
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }

    return noSolution;
});

Thanks a lot!

Because none of Task's constructors take a delegate that returns a value. Worse, they're all variants of Action , which means your first example is actually async void , which comes with its own set of caveat. Looks like Task.Run is what you actually want.

Unfortunately, that's what i always use, but i need to start the task here manually (queued). That's why im creating it only.

The non-generic Task constructor is not async-friendy. The async delegate is async void. What you really want is probably a nested Task<Task>. This is a Task that represents the creation of another Task. When the outer Task completes, it means that the inner Task has been created:
Task<Task> taskTask = new(async () =>
{
    bool noSolution = await AsyncMethodWithBoolReturnValue();

    if (noSolution)
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }
});

Or with result:
Task<Task<bool>> taskTask = new(async () =>
{
    bool noSolution = await AsyncMethodWithBoolReturnValue();

    if (noSolution)
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }

    return noSolution;
});

You can then use the Unwrap method, to create a new proxy Task that represents the completion of both the outer and inner tasks. I don't know what exactly you want to do, but most likely you will need this.
Also make sure that when you Start/RunSynchronously the taskTask, you specify explicitly the TaskScheduler, so that your code complies with the CA2008 guideline:
taskTask.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Default);


Thanks, creating a innertask is a good idea!
